# How to wp_upload_bits() to a sub-folder?

Tags: uploads, media, media-library, wp-remote-get

I am using `wp_upload_bits()` to copy an obtained remote image...

```
$upload = wp_upload_bits($file, '', wp_remote_retrieve_body( $get ));
```

Image source example: `https://logo.clearbit.com/starcomww.com`

The following code seems to obtain the image well enough:

```
$get = wp_remote_get( $image_url ); 
$type = wp_remote_retrieve_header( $get, 'content-type' );
```

`$file` (name of file) is set at eg. `starcom-mediavest-group.png`

So I see how `wp_upload_bits($file`... would set the filename.

But I don't see how to add the image to a **subdirectory** of `uploads` - specifically called `uploads/org_logos`
then `wp_upload_bits` will strip out the slash, believing it to be a non-safe file character, leading to the incorrect file `org_logosstarcom-mediavest-group.png` being placed in the main `uploads` folder. It really wants to put it in `uploads`!

How do I get the image in a **subfolder**?

I'm aware of the PHP function `move_uploaded_file` - but I'm concerned that this would lose any references for a file I'll still need to attach to the Media Library. Regardless, I'm not having much luck moving it with this anyway...

```
// Move it
$thefile = $upload['file'];
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$newfolder = $upload_dir['basedir'].'/org_logos';
move_uploaded_file($thefile, $newfolder);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`wp_upload_bits()` uses [`wp_upload_dir()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_upload_dir/) which fires the `upload_dir` filter allowing you to modify the upload directory's path, sub-directory and URL.

So you can use that filter to "force" `wp_upload_bits()` to use a custom path by doing something like:

```
// Demo to get the image data.
$url = 'https://logo.clearbit.com/starcomww.com';
$content = file_get_contents( $url );

$_filter = true; // For the anonymous filter callback below.
add_filter( 'upload_dir', function( $arr ) use( &$_filter ){
    if ( $_filter ) {
        $folder = '/org_logos'; // No trailing slash at the end.
        $arr['path'] .= $folder;
        $arr['url'] .= $folder;
        $arr['subdir'] .= $folder;
    }

    return $arr;
} );

$filename = wp_basename( $url ) . '.png';
$ret = wp_upload_bits( $filename, null, $content );
var_dump( $ret ); // For testing.

$_filter = false; // Disables the filter.
```

Or you can use a named callback:

```
function my_org_logos_upload_dir( $arr ) {
    $folder = '/org_logos'; // No trailing slash at the end.

    $arr['path'] .= $folder;
    $arr['url'] .= $folder;
    $arr['subdir'] .= $folder;

    return $arr;
}

// Demo to get the image data.
$url = 'https://logo.clearbit.com/starcomww.com';
$content = file_get_contents( $url );

add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'my_org_logos_upload_dir' );

$filename = wp_basename( $url ) . '.png';
$ret = wp_upload_bits( $filename, null, $content );
var_dump( $ret ); // For testing.

remove_filter( 'upload_dir', 'my_org_logos_upload_dir' );
```

### UPDATE

*(In reply to your comments)*

> So, as a filter on `wp_upload_dir()`, that would apply to any file
>   getting uploaded via `wp_upload_dir()`, is that right?

Yes, it would.

But the issue can be prevented by adding/enabling the filter only when you call `wp_upload_bits()` **and** that you want it to use your custom upload path, and then remove/disable the filter after it's applied — to prevent the upload path from being changed when `wp_upload_dir()` is called from other functions or code.

And for that reason, these are my approaches as you have seen in the original answer:

```
// First variant of the code - using an anonymous function.
$_filter = true;  // enables the filter
$_filter = false; // disables the filter

// Second variant of the code - using a named function.
remove_filter( 'upload_dir', 'my_org_logos_upload_dir' ); // enables the filter
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'my_org_logos_upload_dir' );    // disables the filter
```

---

> should the second property of `wp_insert_attachment()` be `$filename`,
>   `$content` or some property of `$ret[here]`?

The second parameter of the [`wp_insert_attachment()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_attachment/) function is the full absolute path to the file that's to be attached to the post.

And on success, `wp_upload_bits()` returns an array with `file` being one of the keys, where the value is the full absolute path of the file that was saved by `wp_upload_bits()`. (You can check the function's [reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_upload_bits/) or [this note](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_upload_bits/#comment-2487) for the other keys.)

So the answer is `$ret['file']`:

```
wp_insert_attachment( array(...), $ret['file'] );
```

Comment: Couple of things: 1. Thanks - this could be really valuable also for other people who I see have posted similar questions. 2. So, as a filter on wp_upload_dir, that would apply to *any* file getting uploaded via wp_upload_dir, is that right? So it could potentially force all uploads to take the same directory? My site may have other uploads destined for *other* directories. 3. I haven't tried this yet as I reverted to file_put_contents, but I assume it works.

Comment: 1. You're welcome. 2. No, because if you look at the code, the filter is removed soon after the `wp_upload_bits()` is called. The only difference is the second code/version uses a named/non-anonymous callback - `my_org_logos_upload_dir()`. 3. Try it out. It wouldn't take a long time.. :)

Comment: Okay FYI, my `wp_upload_bits` variant is all WordPress stuff, so all `wp_*` rather than `file_` methods, eg. `file_get_contents`. Question: following from your second variant, when I then want to `wp_insert_attachment` to the library, should the second property of `wp_insert_attachment()` be `$filename`, `$content` or some property of `$ret[here]`?

Comment: I've updated the answer and hopefully it's more helpful now.

Comment: I uploaded files in a loop and anonymous function created a lot of sub-folders. Usage of named function with add/remove filter resolved that issue.
Also, I don't know why but I had to add a trailing slash BEFORE $folder. Without it I was creating duplicated upload folders like 'uploadsorg_logos'.
Anyway thank you @SallyCJ, your answer was really helpful for me.

Comment: Thanks @Sharpey, you're right about the `/`. :)